# Adding a google map to Ionic Side-Menu project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I want to add  a google map in my ionic app. I search the code here `https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map`
and it works in angular, but not in my side-menu ionic project.
This is page where I want to add the map:

```js
<ion-view view-title="Browse">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>Browse</h1>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I trying just copying and pasting this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

adding my API KEY, but it doesn't work here, maybe because there are different settings in ionic. I found also this: `https://www.joshmorony.com/integrating-google-maps-with-an-ionic-application/`
but I have yet a ionic application, a ionic SIDE-MENU application, I want just to add this map in my app. How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out ionic docs https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-maps/